# Just trying to get a list of users assigned a specific MS licence using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am a bit of a novice where PowerShell is concerned. I do lots of things in ti, but generally have to look them up.

I am trying to get a list of users who have been assigned a specific licence in Office 365. I am using a command which I have used before successfully, but this time it will not work and keeps giving me the following error;

> ```
> Get-MsolUser : The request channel timed out while waiting for a
> reply after 00:00:59.9152154. Increase the timeout value passed to the
> call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The
> time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
> timeout. At line:1 char:1
> + Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "excha ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolUser], TimeoutException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TimeoutException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetUser
> ```

The command I am using is;

```
Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "exchangestandard"}
```

Is there a way if increasing the timeout? Or is there another way of getting this information, other than doing it manually. The company only has about 500 users and this particular licence is only being used by 42.
Thank you.